# SQLite database not saving data

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have a database with a tableView, I've got the database separate in an sqlite file that I made using terminal, and a view that allows me to create my data and then input it into the database though when I click save it doesn't seem to be saved.

Here are my sqlite scripts:

```
-(void) addPatientToDatabase:(Patient *)newPatient {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cities.sqlite"];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "insert into patients (firstName, surname, dob, homeNumber, mobileNumber, email, address, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [newPatient.patientName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [newPatient.patientSurname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [newPatient.patientDoB UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [newPatient.patientHomeNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 5, [newPatient.patientMobileNumber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 6, [newPatient.patientEmail UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 7, [newPatient.patientAddress UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            NSData *dataForPicture = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newPatient.patientPicture);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStatement, 8, [dataForPicture bytes], [dataForPicture length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

and:

```
    Patient *newPatient = [[Patient alloc] init];
    newPatient.patientName = firstnameEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientSurname = surnameEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientDoB = dobEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientHomeNumber = homeNumberEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientMobileNumber = mobileNumberEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientEmail = emailAddressEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientAddress = addressEntry.text;
    newPatient.patientPicture = patientPicture;
    [patients addObject:newPatient];
    [self addPatientToDatabase:newPatient];
```

and:

```
-(NSString *)copyDatabaseToDocuments {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filepath = [documentsPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patients.sqlite"];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) {
        NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patients.sqlite"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:filepath error:nil];
    }
    return filepath;
}

-(void) readPatientsFromDatabaseWithPath:(NSString *)filePath {
    sqlite3 *database;

    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStateMent = "select * from patients";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *surname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *dob = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                NSString *homeNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
                NSString *mobileNumber = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                NSString *email = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];
                NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)];
                NSData *patientData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 8) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 8)];
                UIImage *patientImage = [UIImage imageWithData:patientData];
                Patient *newPatient = [[Patient alloc] init];
                newPatient.patientName = firstName;
                newPatient.patientSurname = surname;
                newPatient.patientDoB = dob;
                newPatient.patientHomeNumber = homeNumber;
                newPatient.patientMobileNumber = mobileNumber;
                newPatient.patientEmail = email;
                newPatient.patientAddress = address;
                newPatient.patientPicture = (UIImage *)patientImage;
                [self.patients addObject:newPatient];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

It doesn't seem to like `if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {`

I tried putting a breakpoint in the middle of the read and it didn't reach the breakpoint also

Sorry that there is so much code and not much text.

Please say if you want any more code or details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any error messages back

Comment: No which is one of the strangest things about it

Comment: have u debug the above code ...

Comment: yes it reaches everywhere

Comment: where r u saving data in sqlite i.e. i can't see the command saving data in sqlite

Comment: I think it is on the third chunk at the bottom above the finalize statement

Comment: @user2568107: Please put a breakpoint or NSLog and check whether data is inserted or not

Comment: Where do I put it cos I have placed loads of breakpoints and they all are activated so far?

Comment: @user2568107: put a NSlog inside the sqlite3_step statement of inserting function and data fetching functions. And print the values inside the data fetching function

Comment: I have done much NSLOG how would that be written?

Comment: 1) `if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            NSLog(@""Insertion successful");
        }`

Comment: 2) After the `[self.patients addObject:newPatient];` add NSLog like `NSLog(@"Data: %@,newPatient);`

Comment: AHa I see that it doesn't get there does that help alot

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%@", sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)); put this before if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

Comment: You say you're not getting any errors, but how could you if you're not checking for them????

Comment: @user2568107: Means both NSLog ? If yes then there is issue with insertion, check whether database file exist and the table is there

Comment: @AdamRichardson -- Wouldn't it be far better to assign the return code to a temp and then both log and test the temp, vs executing sqlite3_prepare twice?  (And the same goes for all the other sqlite3_ calls -- the return code should be captured and logged if not an expected value.)

Comment: @AdamRichardson it reaches there

Comment: @HotLicks yes thats a good point. Also it may reach there but what is it returning, is it saying SQLITE_OK, you need to step through each part and output anything SQLITE is returning you to see what the errors are

Comment: I've found that it doesn't seem to like the if statement `if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)`

Comment: Though I don't know why @AdamRichardson

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)); and see what message it give you instead of SQLITE_DONE

Comment: It gives me 21 and 1 @AdamRichardson

Comment: 1 means SQL error or no database and 21 is a library misuse - http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: if your SQL works ok in terminal then it means the database is not there in which case you need to make sure you are creating it in the app

Comment: I have got the sql file in my directory and have included it

Comment: @AdamRichardson so what do i do about the 1 and 21?

Comment: are you running the checkAndCreateDatabase before executing the command (perhaps in your AppDelegate)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work @AdamRichardson

Comment: Are you testing this on a device as it sounds like it is not copying the database across correctly, unless your SQL is wrong but I dont have your database so I cant say if that is wrong

Comment: I am testing it on the IPhone 6.1 simulator

Comment: try printing out your SQL and running that into the database in terminal to see if it work

Comment: I tried adding something to the database to be loaded but it didn't work as it didn't load the data

Comment: How would I do that @AdamRichardson printing sql that is

Comment: using NSLog, I have to say though going through one of the many SQLite tutorials and starting from scratch would be my recommendation if you are struggling that much

Comment: If you keep helping me i'll give you reputation

Comment: Also I have a deadline of this weekend to finish this app for a company

Comment: Spend the time to insert code to **CHECK ALL RETURN CODES**.  Not simply whether or not they are SQLITE_ROW or whatever, but whether any unexpected value shows up.  Log all unexpected values.  Don't code `if (sqlite3_something() == SQLITE_OK)`, but instead assign the return code to a temp, check the temp in the `if` statement, and log the return code if it's not an "expected" value.  Also, if the return code is bad, do `NSLog(@"Errmsg = %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));`.

Comment: This tutorial will show you how to build the database and an app that communicates with it http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: @AdamRichardson - That is a lousy tutorial.  It doesn't show you how to check return codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you initialsing the database and creating in on the local filesystem before you first use it.

If you are not then you can use the following code to do it:

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databaseName = @"mydatabase.db";
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
// Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
BOOL success;

// Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
// of the database and to copy it over if required
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

// If the database already exists then return without doing anything
if(success) return;

// If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

// Get the path to the database in the application package
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

// Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];


}
```

Comment: I've got the database separate in an sqlite file that I made using terminal

Comment: @user2568107 Have you go any data in the database? If you are you able to get the data out of the database?

Comment: I have no data in the database when the app loads

Comment: @user2568107 Have you tried the code sample I included in this answer as this will ensure there is a writable copy of your database, obviously change the databaseName to your own database you have installed

Comment: @user2568107 if that fails then perhaps look through this tutorial on how to work with sqlite in iOS http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application

Comment: When i try your code it says there are loads of undeclared identifyers

Comment: I have added declarations for databaseName and databasePath now to the code above

Comment: @user2568107 are you calling [self checkAndCreateDatabase]; before you do anything with the database?